# Manufactured solution for $-\operatorname{div}(a(x) \nabla{u}) = f$ when $\alpha(x)$ is discontinuous

Tags: finite-element, convergence, poisson, deal.ii, weak-solution

I'm studying the dealii tutorial number 4,5 and I understand the workflow. I've also been able to find the EOC by using manufactured solution where $f$ is a smooth r.h.s. and $\alpha(x)$ smooth too.

Now I'm interested in checking the EOC when $\alpha(x)$ is discontinuous ([link to Doxygen docs of dealii](https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/step_5.html#Workingwithnonconstantcoefficients))

Let's say I have $\Omega = [-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ and I assume $u(x,y)=\sin(\pi x ) \sin(\pi y)$ to be the solution of

$$- \nabla \cdot (\alpha(x) \nabla{u}) = f$$
with homogeneous Dirichlet b.cs and $\alpha(x)$ defined as in the link.
The forcing term I obtain is:

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
20 \cdot 2\pi^2 \sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi y) \\
2 \pi^2 \sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi y)
\end{cases}$$

Looking at the EOC, it seems that my numerical solution is **not** converging to the true solution $u(x,y)$ (I obtain an EOC which decreases from 0.23 to 0.02...) So I'm wondering if this approach is not okay.

- How can I construct a manufactured solution when the $\alpha(x)$ is not continuous?

---

**EDIT:**

Using that $\alpha(x)$, I could set $\nabla{u}=[1,20]^T$ on $B_{1/2}(0,0)$ and $\nabla{u}=[20,40]^T$ outside $B_{1/2}(0,0)$.

This implies that $\alpha(x,y) \nabla{u}$ is continuous, actually it's constant, hence I obtain $f=0$. Also, $$u(x,y)= x+20y$$ in $B_{1/2}(0,0)$, and $$u(x,y)=20x+40y$$ outside $B_{1/2}(0,0)$. With this argument, I always have a jump in $\nabla{u}$ due to $\alpha(x,y)$.

However, I'm still facing issues in showing the convergence, and I think this may be due to the fact that I have $f=0$ as forcing term.

---

**EDIT^2:**

Following the comment from @MaximUmansky, let $\alpha \nabla{u} = \vec{f}$ such that
$$-\operatorname{div}(\vec{f}) = f_x + f_y= \sin(x)+\cos(y)$$

so $\vec{f}=[\cos(x), - \sin(y)]^T$

With $\alpha$ as above, we need $\nabla{u} = [\frac{\cos(x)}{20}, -\frac{\sin(y)}{20}]$ in $B_{1/2}(0,0)$

and $\nabla{u} = [\cos(x),-\sin(y)]$ outside $B_{1/2}(0,0)$.

So I have, in $B_{1/2}(0,0)$, $$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{20}(\sin(x)+\cos(y))$$

and $$u(x,y)=\sin(x) +\cos(y)$$ outside $B_{1/2}(0,0)$.

Comment: grad(u) has to be discontinuous to make the product $\alpha$ grad(u) smooth. For example, in 1D make $\alpha$=1 in x$\in [0,0.5]$ and $\alpha=2$ in x$\in$ [0.5,1], and $\partial_x$u=2 in the left half-domain, $\partial_x$u=1 in the right half-domain.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Thanks, I see now why $\alpha \nabla u$ needs to be continuous (I need to take its divergence), but I can't see how I can do this in practice. I mean, $u$ is what I have to find with my solver! What should I change in my problem above?

Comment: I think I got your point: $u_x = 2$ implies $u(x)=2x$ on the left-half domain, while on the right-half we have $u(x)=x$. I'm trying to work this out in the 2D case @MaximUmansky

Comment: @MaximUmansky I worked out a possible way in my edit, but the r.h.s $f$ turns out to be $0$ now, and I'm having some problems in showing the convergence. Do you have any hint, maybe another simple solution with a non-trivial $f$?

Comment: I mean, I'd like to find a discontinuous $f$ as r.h.s. @MaximUmansky

Comment: Have checked this [question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20091/method-of-manufactured-solutions-for-non-differentiable-coefficients)?

Comment: @bobinthebox Yes, that suggested solution was for RHS=0. For some other RHS, it is similar - in 1D let $\alpha$ grad(u) be some f(x) which is not constant. Now you know that d/dx(f) = RHS, so you find f for given RHS, after that find u(x) since f is known and $\alpha$ is known.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Thanks for your useful comments. I applied your approach in the last edit: is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @bobinthebox Yes, however we need to make the solution u(x,y) continuous; u(x,y) in each half-domain allows an additive constant, and that should be used to make the global solution continuous. In principle discontinuous solutions are sometimes possible but they require special care and are more difficult to interpret.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to find such a constant in my last example, but I am not able to do this: what value could I choose? @MaximUmansky

Comment: In 1D, say your solution in [0,0.5] is sin(x)/20, and in [0.5,1] it is sin(x)+C. Then at x=1/2 you need to solve 0.05 sin(1/2) = sin(1/2) + C, to find C.

Comment: Yeah in 1D it's straightforward, but my problem is in 2D: I think is not possible to do this with my last attempt, unless I move to polar coordinates as cfdlab wrote in the answer, right? @MaximUmansky

Comment: Oh, you can certainly do it in 2D Cartesian coordinates. The simplest thing would be to look for solutions that are independent of the y coordinate. That would be the case if the boundary conditions in the y coordinate are zero gradient, and the forcing function (source) is independent of y. But it is not hard to make up a solution with nontrivial dependence on y., e.g., assuming separation of variables.

Comment: Unfortunately I got stuck because I don't know how to impose that condition honestly. In my edit I think there's the situation you've just said, i.e. separation of variables. However, it's really not clear how to impose continuity at the interface @MaximUmansky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cfdlab's answer gives a general way to construct solutions for discontinuous coefficients, but here is a slightly more theoretical perspective to it as well. All of this can be understood in 1d, so imagine all of the functions below to be functions of just one argument $x$ for a moment.

First, you can't just choose any $u$ and $\alpha$ to obtain a function $f(x)$. That's because in general, if $u$ is continuous and $\alpha$ is discontinuous, then $\alpha \nabla u = \alpha\frac{du}{dx}$ is a discontinuous function and if you take the negative divergence of it (we're in 1d, so the divergence is again just $\frac{d}{dx}$), you end up with a function $f$ that is not, in fact, a function but a distribution: It has delta functions in all of those places where $\alpha \nabla u$ is discontinuous. One can, in theory, solve the PDE you are interested in with such right hand sides $f$, but not easily with finite elements and for sure not if you use quadrature, because the way you integrate the right hand side terms doesn't see these delta functions.

Secondly, the Poisson equation *models* some physical behavior. In general, this would be a diffusive process of some sort where $j=-\alpha\nabla u$ is a *flux* and the divergence of the flux equals the source terms $f$. Fluxes are generally thought to be continuous functions, though not necessarily smooth: they can have kinks, and so their derivatives can be discontinuous. That means that if $\alpha$ is discontinuous, then $\nabla u$ must be discontinuous as well, in such a way that $-\alpha\nabla u$ is continuous again. What this implies is that you can't just choose $\alpha$ and $u$ independently. At its heart, that is why @cfdlab in their answer above starts by prescribing $\alpha$ and the *flux* (rather than $\alpha$ and $u$) and then deriving what $u$ needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the coefficient of the form
$$
\alpha = \begin{cases}
\alpha_1 & r < 0.5 \\
\alpha_2 & r > 0.5
\end{cases}
$$
it is useful to work in polar coordinates. You build two pieces of the solution
$$
u_1(r,\theta), \qquad r < 0.5
$$
and
$$
u_2(r,\theta), \qquad r > 0.5
$$
Then at the interface you ensure solution and flux continuity
$$
u_1(0.5, \theta) = u_2(0.5, \theta), \qquad \alpha_1 \partial_r u_1(0.5,\theta) = \alpha_2 \partial_r u_2(0.5,\theta)
$$
Maybe you can try to build a solution of the form
$$
u_i(r,\theta) = f_i(r) g(\theta), \qquad i=1,2
$$
You can first try to build a purely radial solution, which should be easy to do, it will be just like a 1d problem.

Note that the discontinuity is on a circle and to observe good convergence you must make a mesh that aligns with this circle.

If you know fenics, you can see below example where the mesh is made in gmsh
https://github.com/cpraveen/fembook/tree/master/fenics/step-10

Comment: Thanks @cfdlab for your answer. I tried to follow your argument, and tried to build $u_1$, $u_2$, by setting $$\partial_r ( \alpha \partial_r u)=r$$ with $\alpha$ discontinuous as in my link, and I obtained $u^1_r(r)=\frac{1}{40} r^2$ and $u^2_r(r)=\frac{r^2}{2}$. Imposing the continuity at the interface I found $u(r)=\frac{r^3}{120} + \frac{13}{320}$ and $u_2(r)=\frac{r^3}{3}$. You can see that it's continuous at $r=0.5$, but I'm a bit afraid that maybe I should have written the original equation in polar coordinates. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, write PDE in polar coordinates, find a solution and then write solution in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Okay, so if I look at a purely radial solution I may consider $$- \frac{1}{r} \partial_r ( \alpha r \partial_r u) = 1$$ By setting $\alpha r \partial_r u= f$ I got $ \partial_r f=-r$, and finally $u_1(r)=- \frac{r^2}{80} - \frac{19}{320}$ and $u_2(r)=- \frac{r^2}{4}$, where the constant has been chosen to ensure continuity at $r=0.5$.
Of course now I'll use the fact $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Looks correct. This is a quadratic solution which an FEM can compute exactly. Try a more nonlinear solution.

Comment: You mean to start with  something like $\alpha r \partial_r u = \sin(r)$ and then get $u$ ? @cfdlab

Comment: Take the PDE, $-\frac{1}{r}\partial_r (\alpha(r) r \partial_r u) = g(r)$ and in your notation you have to solve $\partial_r f(r) = -r g(r)$. Choose some $g(r)$ so that you can still solve for $f(r)$.